# Best resources for learning how to prevent malicious usage?

Tags: security, botattack, ddos

I'd like to work on creating a public website, but I'm concerned about the potential for it to be the target of some attack. I'm aware of some of the more common attacks like XSS, query injection, DDOS, and spam bots, but before I can feel comfortable making the website public, I'd want to be sure that I've accounted for as many potential attack points as possible. **What are the best resources for learning about potential attack points and the best ways to protect them?**

Comment: Have you looked at sans.org?  They offer security training, and I believe security training for coders.